# symfony create query builder

Tags: php, sql, symfony, query-builder

I'm newbie in symfony and I would like some advices for creating a query builder statement. Is pretty simple, the idea is to get the data from a third entity.

I have the entities:

```
/**
* Entity
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="LoungepassBundle\Entity\LoungepassRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="loungepass_loungepass")
*
*/

class Loungepass{

  /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
  private $id;

// ...

/**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\Agency", inversedBy="loungepasses")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="agency_id", referencedColumnName="iata8", nullable=false)
   */
  private $agency;

//...

}
```

Agency Entity

```
class Agency {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=8, name="iata8")
     */
    protected $id;

//...

  /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="LoungepassBundle\Entity\Loungepass", mappedBy="agency")
     */
    protected $loungepasses;

    /**
    * @var Market
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Market")
    * @ORM\JoinColumns({
    *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sales_country", referencedColumnName="id")
    * })
    */
    private $market;

//...
}
```

I would like to do a query, like this:

```
public function queryBySlugInContext($slug, $user) {

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder("l")
    ->where('l.slug = :slug')
    ->setParameter('slug', $slug);

    if(count($user->getAgencies()) > 0){
      $query->andWhere(':agencyIds MEMBER OF l.agencies')
      ->setParameter('agencyIds',$user->getAgencies());
    }
```

Able to access the information from the market attribute located in the agency entity.So basically, retrieve information from the Market Entity.

any suggestions?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

I modified a bit your code but the mind is here

When you have to access to retrieve data from other tables just keep in mind to use differents mysql join accessible with doctrine

```
public function queryBySlugInContext($slug, $user) {

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder("l")
    ->where('l.slug = :slug')
    ->setParameter('slug', $slug);
if(0 !== count($user->getAgencies())) {
    $query = $query->innerJoin('l.agency', 'a')
                   ->andWhere('a.id IN(:userAgenciesIds)')
                   ->setParameter('userAgenciesIds', array_map(function(Agency $agency) {
                       return $agency->getId();
                    }, $user->getAgencies());
}
```

You should take a time to read some content on internet like for example the doctrine [query builder documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

Comment: Thank you @Mcsky, yes I read in different websites, but still was difficult for me to understand. Could you help me to build the query for getting the data from the third table, or some links that can help me. Thank you

Comment: why do I need an array_map and the function, in that function I can also call the markets, $agency->getMarkets() ?

Comment: "difficult to understand" was not the right word, I would like documentation or examples to retrieve data from different tables